# Display jmeter failed assertion logs in jenkins console output

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I have Integrated Jmeter with Jenkins. Sometimes due to Jmeter assertion failure,the Whole Jenkins build gets fail which is expected for my requirement.

Now, Is there any way to display the Jmeter failed request (which is an assertion failure one mentioned above) on Jenkins Console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) at the same level of requests you want to capture (or a level higher, see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article to learn why does the placement matter
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       prev.getAssertionResults().each { assertionResult ->
           if (assertionResult.failure) {
               println('Request ' + prev.getSampleLabel() + ' failed with ' + assertionResult.failureMessage)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. That's it, whenever a request fails due to failed assertion you will have the relevant line printed to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) (therefore to Jenkins console log)

   [image]

Comment: Is there a way to show the request/response body and headers for failed requests in Jenkins?

Comment: You could use a listener i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) like it's described in [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter) article, it will generate XML file with request and response data, the file can be [archived](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) so it would be added to your build dashboard, you will be able to open it with [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener